# Next is not a field

Tags: java

I write this piece of code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void remove(K key){
        if(this.containsKey(key)){
            int slotNumber = Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % size;
            TableEntry<K,V> previous = (TableEntry<K,V>)elements [slotNumber];

            // first in row
            if(previous.getKey().equals(key)){
                elements[slotNumber] = elements[slotNumber].next;
            }
            else{
                while(!key.equals(previous.next.getKey())){
                    previous = previous.next;   
                }
                previous.next = previous.next.next
            }
        }
    }
```

In the line:

```
elements[slotNumber] = elements[slotNumber].next;
```

there is an error. Error said: Next cannot be resolved or it is not a field.
I think it is because I tried to access to object which doesn't have attribute next. I tried to cast to (TableEntry), but this intervention does not helped me.

Here is complete class: [HashTable](http://hastebin.com/gehujazete.coffee)

Can you help me by telling me what I doing wrong?
Many thanks!

Comment: if next is a method, you should use next()

Comment: what type of object is elements[slotNumber]

Comment: You have asked "What is your proposal/solution" on two different answers. The proposal/solution is to eliminate ***all*** casts. The fact that you are casting anything is a sign that your code is wrong. The purpose of generics is to eliminate casts and the unsafety that brings.

Answer (score 1):

`previous` is an instance of `TableEntry`.

Your inner class `TableEntry` does not have a field called `next`.

Therefore `previous.next` is not valid.

By the way, why re-invent the wheel? Java already has many Maps.

Comment: I have not made a proposal. I've explained the cause of the error. But it seems to me you have made a double-linked list but have forgotten to put the actual links in (prev, next).

Answer (score 1):

`elements[slotNumber]` is of type V so there is no guarantee it has field `next`.

Comment: What is your solution for this?

Comment: Please explain what do you try to do with this line:
`elements[slotNumber] = elements[slotNumber].next;`